# Vector projection of a vector exactly in the opposite direction to the other vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am trying to understand linear algebra for some data science self study that I am doing. One of the basic ideas is the vector dot product. Now I have seen videos explaining that tell the geometric intuition of a dot product of $\vec{v}.\vec{w}$ is that when $\vec{v}$ is projected onto ${\vec{w}}$.

How that is done is by dropping a perpendicular from the edge of $\vec{w}$.

But my question is how is that geometrically possible when $\vec{v}$ is just in the exact opposite direction of $\vec{w}$ ?

For example:

[image]

How would you get a perpendicular from the end  of $\vec{v}$ to the end of $\vec{w}$ or vice versa. In fact you could come up with a variety of configuration where the perpendicular from the end of 1 vector would never meet the second vector.

**So how does vector dot product work geometrically in these cases ?**

Comment: You can seen the problem with the strict geometrical interpretation of vector dot products. That is why they are defined using algebra instead.

Comment: @Somos Yes but how would the projection look like ?

Comment: That has been answered by user572435 in his answer already.

Comment: @Somos user572435 said that it would be the vector itself, but if you read the comments I am unable to understand how that fits into the whole intuition about shadows and using perpendiculars.

Comment: The key word is "shadows".  Projecting is essentially the same as casting shadows.

Comment: Well, what is the shadow cast by $\vec w$ onto the line defined by $\vec v$? Imagine laying two rods end to end on the ground: what do their shadows look like?

Comment: @amd Fine. Then in such special cases what should I use to find the length of the projection, because clearly the technique of drawing perpendiculars dont work here.

Comment: Sure it does, if you’re willing to entertain the idea of a zero-length line segment. The foot of the perpendicular from the endpoint of the directed line segment $\vec w$ is that endpoint itself.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a series of vectors converging toward one of the vector you draw and draw for each of them the perpendicular projection along the axis led by the other vector. You'll figure out that their perpendicular projection gets closer and closer from the actual vector.

So to answer your question, in the case the vectors are collinear (along the same axis), their projection is "just themselves", don't forget to add a minus sign to their norms while doing the dot product in the case they are pointing in an opposite direction.

Hope it helps and that I'm clear enough, I'm not an English native so it's sometimes difficult for me to be as clear as I'd like to be.

Comment: I am afraid I dont understand your first paragraph clearly. But if you say that vectors which are co linear along the same axis have projections which are themselves then the act of drawing a perpendicular is just meaningless right ? I mean its just done for our understanding and doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Maybe it will be clearer with the formula of the dot product: x.y=|| x ||*|| y || * cos(thêta) where theta is the angle between your two vectors and ||z|| the norm (length) of a vector z  . Doing the perpendicular projection is the same as calculating geometrically the cos(theta) term. So when your vectors are collinear , the angle is either 0 degree or 180 degree so the cos() therm is worth either 1 or -1

Comment: Then why is it that when dot products are introduced people say to draw a perpendicular from 1 vector to the other. That makes no sense in case of co linear vectors.

Comment: This is a way to compute the value geometrically. ||X||*cos(theta) is what you compute when you draw your perpendicular projection ie the length of the projection equals ||X||*cos(theta), X being the vector you are projecting along the direction of your y vector. If they are collinear, the perpendicular projection thing doesn't really hold anymore I agree, what is left from your cos() term is in this case only 1 or -1

Comment: So my question that is if the perpendicular thing doesn't hold in all cases, how can I geometrically think about projection that would work in all cases ? Also how would you add 2 vectors that are co linear ? What would it even mean to do that?

Comment: Try to draw vectors that are closer and closer from each other but not 100% collinear and draw for each of them their perpendicular projection (the angle between your two vectors going to zero) , I'm sure you'll this way get rid of what bother you ;-) you can try doing the same for an angle going to 180 degree. Please take the time to draw the projections with a pen and a piece of paper though.

Comment: I have uploaded the image of what you asked me to do [here](https://imgur.com/a/PnOXkO2). Can you please tell me if Case 3 and Case 4 are correct ? I mean Case 3 involves going in the opposite direction and Case 4 is according to what you say the projection is one of the operand vectors. I still am unable to understand what you want me to find.

Comment: Any good vector visualization tools you recommend ?